# Custom methods for use in spring security expression language annotations

Tags: spring-security

I have classes that extends Controller class

```
public class MyClass extends MainController {
...
}
```

And a MainController like this

```
@Controller
public abstract class MainController extends MultiActionController {
...
}
```

I would like to create a custom method like 'checkUser' to be used somehow like this:

```
@PreAuthorize("checkUser('attribute')")
public class MyClass extends MainController {
...
}
```

And add this method in MainController

```
@Controller
public abstract class MainController extends MultiActionController {

   public boolean checkUser(String key) {
     ...
     return true;
   }
}
```

My question is this. If it is possible, how would I go about configuring it in the spring xml configuration files and come someone give me an example of a custom method used in this way?

Thanks